# bash script variable in curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl

```bash
bash get-token.sh | grep x-subject-token | awk '{print $2}' >> token.txt

token=`cat token.txt`

echo $token this is true

data=`curl -s -H "X-Auth-Token: ${token}"  -X GET "https://url"`

echo $token = correct token but $data is invalid.
```

When I write the token in curl and run it manually I get the correct data.
How can I use this token in my script?

Comment: Run curl with `-v` to get verbose output. Then you can check the headers you send and the response code. At first glance, I don't see an obvious error. grep and awk could be combined though: `awk '/x-subject-token/{print $2}'`

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `>token.txt` instead of `>>token.txt`? You always only want a single token in that file and not all previous tokens plus the current one

Comment: And what exactly is meant by "$data is invalid"? _How_ is it invalid? Empty? Unexpected? Is the format off?

Comment: data format json 
When I run it as data=`curl -s -H "X-Auth-Token:gAAAAAAAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -X GET "https://url"` I get the data I want

Comment: That didn't answer my question. How is the data invalid? Can you run your script with `-x` to enable debug output? Have you run `curl -v`?

Comment: Does your token only have letters and numbers or does it have special chars?

Comment: I notice that there is no space after the colon for the manual curl command, but you have a space in the quotes before the token in your script.  Could that be your issue?